# Trying to replace Full state name to abbreviation in PHP search

Tags: php, mysql, html

I'm trying to replace Illinois with IL in a city /state /zip search; or, any state for that matter.  I have states stored as abbr. so I need that to be in the inputed search.  I'm trying:

```
if(isset($_GET['search_loc'])&&isset($_GET['search_style'])) {
    $search_loc = $_GET['search_loc'];
    $search_style = $_GET['search_style'];
    if(!empty($search_loc)||!empty($search_style)) {

        /* HERE!!! */ $search_loc = str_replace('Illinois', 'IL', $search_loc); // ***Here!!!***

        $query = "SELECT
                    name, street, city, state, zip_code, phone_number, style, description, time
                  FROM music_spots
                  WHERE CONCAT(city, ', ', state, ', ', zip_code) LIKE '%$search_loc%' // and so on...
```

But, this isn't working.  Any ideas on how I could do this?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly suggest storing and retrieving the state name with the database. I can assure you that hard-coding is not the answer.

Comment: Right, but users are going to enter city, state, and zip as: Chicago  IL, 60605 typically.

Comment: Ok. Regardless of what they enter you could eliminate hard-coded replacements by including the state name with the rest of your like statement. They both achieve the same result, however your logic breaks several key principles, is not scalable and is much less efficient.

Comment: I will try having a an abbr. state name and full state name in the database and include both in the in the CONCAT part of the query.  Why is this not scalable?  What would be a better approach?

Comment: See my answer for something approaching scalability. Another option is to index city, state, state_abbr, and zip in a single index and split the user's input and compare them against those exact columns.

Answer (score 1):

You should really be using geolocation/address services for this. Searching against a SQL database in that manner won't use an index at all and will get incredibly slow as the data set grows.

If geolocation isn't a viable option, you could at least use a [fulltext index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) and have a different table that has city, state, state_abbr, and zip in the fulltext column. So in this example, you would index "Chicago IL Illinois 60605". This would also find results with less of a match like "Chicago IL Illinois 60610" but this would by no means be a geolocation search.

You would then just search the `location` table with the user's input and join it to the other table:

```
SELECT 
m.name, m.street, m.city, m.state, m.zip_code, m.phone_number, m.style, m.description, m.time, 
MATCH (loc.location) AGAINST ('Chicago, IL 60605') as score
FROM location AS loc
INNER JOIN music_spots AS m ON m.location_id = loc.id
WHERE MATCH (loc.location) AGAINST ('Chicago, IL 60605');
```

Or full name:

```
SELECT 
m.name, m.street, m.city, m.state, m.zip_code, m.phone_number, m.style, m.description, m.time,
MATCH (loc.location) AGAINST ('Chicago, Illinois 60605') as score
FROM location AS loc
INNER JOIN music_spots AS m ON m.location_id = loc.id
WHERE MATCH (loc.location) AGAINST ('Chicago, Illinois 60605');
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do a pretty simple function like this:

```
function abbreviate_state($state_to_abreviate){
    //This information never changes
    $full_state = array('Alabama', 'Alazka', 'Arizona'); //for the 50 states
    $ab_state   = array('AL','AK', 'AZ');
    //Here we search and replace the state with the abbreviation
    return str_replace($full_state, $ab_state, $state_to_abreaviate);
}
```

you can put this in a  `function.php` and call it whenever you want, wherever you are.